# How to access a config item by index in Laravel 8.x

Tags: php, laravel-8

I have the following array under the config folder.

**config/currencies.php**

```
return [ 
    "CAD" => [
        "name" => 'Canadian Dollar (C$)',
        "value" => 1,
        "symbol" => '$'     
     ],
     "AUD" => [
         "name" => 'Australian Dollar (A$)',
         "value" => 2,
         "symbol" => '$'      
     ],
     "USD" => [
         "name" => 'US Dollar (US$)',
         "value" => 3,
         "symbol" => '$'   
     ],
     "YEN" => [
         "name" => 'Japanese Yen (¥)',
         "value" => 4,
         "symbol" => '¥'      
     ],
     "INR" => [
         "name" => 'Indian Rupee (₹)',
         "value" => 5,
         "symbol" => '₹'       
     ],
    "EUR" => [
         "name" => 'Euro (€)',
         "value" => 6,
         "symbol" => '€'     
     ]   
];
```

How can I access each item by index? I was expecting that `config('currencies')[1][0]` would give me 'Australian Dollar (A$)' as output, but it is showing an error. Can you please advise how I can access the array using an index number?

Comment: `config('currencies.AUD.name')`

Comment: i need to access it using index number. config('currencies')[0];

Comment: the indexes are what you named them and they are not integers

Comment: is there any way i can access items using index numbers?

Comment: you would have to use `array_values` then iterate through each element and then use `array_values` on those arrays ... is there a reason you actually need to do it by an index as the actual order of these items should not mean anything outside this file (or in general) ... do you want this `value` field to be the index or something?

Answer (score 3):

The right way is to access it using dot syntax. Like:

```
config('currencies.AUD')
```

If you have to use an array index you can do something like this:

```
array_values(config('currencies'))[0]
```

[Link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#accessing-configuration-values)

Answer (score 0):

You will use array_values() function for key conversation then you access values as you want.

```
$input =[ 
    "CAD" => [
        "name" => 'Canadian Dollar (C$)',
        "value" => 1,
        "symbol" => '$'
               
     ],
     "AUD" => [
         "name" => 'Australian Dollar (A$)',
         "value" => 2,
         "symbol" => '$'
               
     ],
     "USD" => [
         "name" => 'US Dollar (US$)',
         "value" => 3,
         "symbol" => '$'
               
     ],
     "YEN" => [
         "name" => 'Japanese Yen (¥)',
         "value" => 4,
         "symbol" => '¥'
               
     ],
     "INR" => [
         "name" => 'Indian Rupee (₹)',
         "value" => 5,
         "symbol" => '₹'
               
     ],
    "EUR" => [
         "name" => 'Euro (€)',
         "value" => 6,
         "symbol" => '€'
               
     ]
    
    
];
$flipped = array_values($input);

print_r($flipped[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dot syntax:

```
config('filename.key.nested_key')
```

In your example:

```
 config('currencies.CAD.name')
```